# How to get info about crash from core file?

Tags: c++, linux, coredump

I have run a software and it crashed and left a core file. Now how I can read the info about crash by using core file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the

```
$ gdb /path/to/application /path/to/corefile
```

Take a look at the `gdb` manpage for more information...

[In this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html) you can have some information too.

Comment: Can I use the instruction you gave even if I did not compile the executable with -g (with debug info) option?

Comment: @Narek: it'll be a bit harder... :)    The -g option is to generate the symbols, so that you can analyse the dump using them. Without them, you won't have reference to variables, etc

Answer (score 1):

you will need `gdb` for this -- have a look here: http://linux.bytesex.org/gdb.html